# Postfix and Ownclound mysql authentication

Tags: login, mysql, postfix

i'm using ubuntu 12.04 with roundcube/postfix and owncloud installed, and using mysql as login authentication.

i would like to know if it's possible to make single login for these apps (without LDAP) ?
so the users don't have to login for every apps on the server

postfix and owncloud is using different format/encryption for password stored in mysql
so even they are on the same database.. i still can't figure out, how to make them using
single table for username and password

Comment: What do you mean by "every app on the server"?

Comment: i mean every "web" apps.., the first step is to make the roundcube and owncloud use the same password table, or the same login session. Well i don't know how the integration should work..

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing, but I think possible. Would have to use a function that updates the database in their respective roles both encryption

Answer (score 0):

One way you can acomplish that is with triger in my sql which will update additional field postfix_pass in owncloud user db every time new user is created or user pass changed.

This is not best solution because of sha encryption of postfix users pass field.

In postfix you configure auth.cfm to authenticate against owncloud user database but with pass from added field.

This can be a quick fix until you find a solution to use original owncloud user table for postfix authentication.